# Fulfilled Commitments based on Reputation

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-fulfillment

I think there should be another way to fulfill commitments other than by asking/answering 10 questions/answers total: Reputation.

For example, I've got [223 reputation on GraphicDesign.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/82/muntoo), but I've only got 7 questions/answers. (Due to the high number of answers and the low number of questions, it's difficult to find unanswered questions.)

[I fit into this category:](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design)

> - 150 users with 200+ rep (on pace for 71 users at 90 days)

So, shouldn't it be:

```
if((user.reputation >= 200) || ((user.questions + user.answers) >= 10))
    user.commitment.fulfilled = true;
```

Comment: gained rep or including the possible 100 rep bonus for account association?

Comment: Hmmm... I just got an email saying I fulfilled my commitment... with 9 answers and 223 rep.

Comment: your profile shows 10 though

Comment: @Tobias Yeah, I just added another answer (*after* the email saying I fulfilled my commitment).

Comment: so someone took a sneak preview into the future ;) maybe the criterion is not exactly 10 posts but actually considering upvotes or acceptance as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there aren't enough questions to answer, then you should ask some!  If there are no questions to ask, maybe the site is doomed anyway...

We don't want to use a straight rep score because we don't want people to fulfill their commitment by just posting one highly voted answer or question.

I am open to changing the number of questions / answers or doing some combination, but I don't like the idea of just 200 rep being enough to fulfill the commitment, and I like that 10 questions or answers is very simple and easy to understand right now.